# Extract Values Between Pattern Match

Tags: regex, parsing, unix, sed

I'm trying to extract any numerical values between a pattern match in a text file.

**Parsed Log File Text**

```
> GET /pub/data/nccf/com/hiresw/prod/hiresw.20180921/hiresw.t00z.nmmb_2p5km.f25.conus.grib2
```

I want to pull the `25` from `f25` in nmmb_2p5km.f**25**.conus.grib2

**Attempted Code**

```
sed -e 's/nmmb_2p5km\(.*\)grib2/\1/'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
log="GET /pub/data/nccf/com/hiresw/prod/hiresw.20180921/hiresw.t00z.nmmb_2p5km.f25.conus.grib2"
sed 's/.*nmmb_2p5km[^0-9]*\([0-9]*\)[^0-9]*grib2.*/\1/' <<< "$log"
```

The `.*nmmb_2p5km[^0-9]*\([0-9]*\)[^0-9]*grib2.*` pattern matches

- `.*` - any 0+ chars
- `nmmb_2p5km` - a literal substring
- `[^0-9]*` - 0+ non-digit chars
- `\([0-9]*\)` - Capturing group 1 (later referred to with `\1` from the replacement pattern): 0+ digits
- `[^0-9]*` - 0+ non-digit chars
- `grib2.*` - `grib2` and any 0+ chars.

Alternatively, you may use `grep` with a PCRE pattern like

```
grep -Po 'nmmb_2p5km\D*\K\d+' <<< "$log"
```

**Details**

- `nmmb_2p5km` - a literal substring
- `\D*` - 0+ non-digit chars
- `\K` - match reset oeprator discarding all text matched so far
- `\d+` - 1+ digits.

See the [online `sed` and `grep` demo](https://ideone.com/7knuDz).

Comment: PER. FECT. Thank you for the very thorough and complete answer!

Answer (score 0):

Using perl one-liner

```
> export log="GET /pub/data/nccf/com/hiresw/prod/hiresw.20180921/hiresw.t00z.nmmb_2p5km.f25.conus.grib2"
> perl -ne ' BEGIN { $x=$ENV{log};$x=~s/(.+?)(\d+)\.conus\.(.+)/\2/g; print "$x\n"; exit } '
25
>
```